# Swift Undefined architecture x86_64 in Xcode 6 Beta 5

Tags: swift, couchbase-lite, couchcocoa

Steps to reproduce:

1. Create a new single page application in swift using Xcode 6 beta 5
2. Add TouchDB.framework and CouchCocoa.framework to project by following this [steps](https://github.com/couchbaselabs/TouchDB-iOS/wiki/Guide:Adding-TouchDB-To-Your-App)
3. Add a new swift file to project and type
4. Create a bridging header file and import CouchCocoa:

   import < CouchCocoa/CouchCocoa.h >
5. Add a new swift file to project and type

   class TestData : CouchMode { }
6. Build the project,

> ld: warning: ignoring file /Users/Robin/Documents/TouchTest/Frameworks/TouchDB.framework/TouchDB, missing required architecture x86_64 in file /Users/Robin/Documents/TouchTest/Frameworks/TouchDB.framework/TouchDB (3 slices)
>
> ld: warning: ignoring file /Users/Robin/Documents/TouchTest/Frameworks/CouchCocoa.framework/CouchCocoa, missing required architecture x86_64 in file /Users/Robin/Documents/TouchTest/Frameworks/CouchCocoa.framework/CouchCocoa (3 slices)
>
> Undefined symbols for architecture x86_64:
>     "_OBJC_CLASS_$_CouchModel", referenced from:
>         _OBJC_CLASS_$__TtC9TouchTest8TestData in ViewController.o
>     "_OBJC_METACLASS_$_CouchModel", referenced from:
>         _OBJC_METACLASS_$__TtC9TouchTest8TestData in ViewController.o
>
> ld: symbol(s) not found for architecture x86_64
>   clang: error: linker command failed with exit code 1 (use -v to see invocation)

Any help here?
This works previously on Xcode 6 Beta 4

Apologize for bad english

Comment: Does it build for the actual device?

Comment: Have you seen that you can use CocoaPods to install TouchDB? [see this](http://cocoapods.org/?q=touch%20db) I have myself used CocoaPods in Xcode 6 Beta 5 and have installed some pods everything works fine.

Comment: @sapi I don't know. I'm very very new to Xcode and swift.

Comment: you should follow the steps provided by Couchbase , its well explained , i resolved my issue same way